# Do you know the name of this item for crimping two cables?

Tags: components, cables, crimp

I just need the name of this component.

[image: Image of Crimp]

Comment: I think this is one of those words which will vary by country and even locale. Some might call it a "U-joint crimp", "butt splice/connector", or "ferrule", etc. Problem is, there are several connector types similar to this, and nobody knows exactly what to call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are specifically known as U-joint crimps. The cables are overlapped into a U-shaped peice of metal, which is then crushed around them.

Butt crimps do a similar job, except there are two crimping points with the cables butted together and crimped into their own end.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a "[butt splice](https://www.panduit.com/content/dam/panduit/en/products/media/8/88/188/7188/102247188.pdf)" or a "butt connector" (crimp connector). They come in insulated and non-insulated and some have different sizes of holes at each end.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a ferrule or crimp(ed) ferrule.